# NHibernate QueryOver filter by collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I want to filter a db table(with a composite key Id1 and Id2) by a memory collection using nHhibernate.

```
class Item{ int Id1; int Id2; }

var collection = new List<Item>();

var list = _session
    .QueryOver<MyDbTable>()
    .Where(x => collection.Any(y => y.Id1 == x.Id1 && y.Id2 == x.Id2))
    .List();
```

The error I get by doing this is "Unrecognised method call:System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any". I tried also to use FirstOrDefault method and compare the result with null, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Linq methods in NHibernate.

If you want to verify if property is in a collection, you can use `IsIn` method, but in your case we don't want to check if a single property is in a collection, we are looking for a composite key.

To solve your problem, you can iterate `collection` to construct your restriction:

```
var disjunctionOptions = new Disjunction();

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var conjunction = new Conjunction();
    conjunction.Add<MyDbTable>(x => x.Id1 == item.Id1);
    conjunction.Add<MyDbTable>(x => x.Id2 == item.Id2);

    disjunctionOptions.Add(conjunction);
}

var list = _session
    .QueryOver<MyDbTable>()
    .Where(disjuntionOptions)
    .List();
```

With that you will have a correct result for your query with composite key.

> **Note**: `IsIn` is to check if a single property is in a colletion (or array). It will give wrong results if used separately (in each property) because you are using composite key.

Comment: I agree that my version will not work but I definitely would look for another solution anyway. Do you realize the size of SQL generated by your disjunction query when the collection has some decent size, like 100 elements, or may be 1000?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyZimarev, the limit of a SQL query lenght is 65,536 * Network Packet Size (default 4KB). The limit of 2100 parameters will exceed before the the SQL query lenght. For example, you can't use IsIn using a collection with more than 2100 elements. This is not a particular problem of my solution, and I'm using the minimum number of parameters for this case. I agree that my query with ands and ors will be longer, but it doesn't increase the number of parameters. Of course, HQL can be used if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have you get confused and use [QueryOver API](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html) while believing you use [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate). In this case, for using linq2nh, change your code to:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
...

var collection = new List<Item>();

var list = _session
    .Query<MyDbTable>()
    .Where(x => collection.Any(y => y.Id1 == x.Id1 && y.Id2 == x.Id2))
    .ToList();
```

The `using` is required for switching `QueryOver` to `Query`, as `ISession.Query` is an extension method defined in `NHibernate.Linq` namespace. And with Linq API instead of `QueryOver`, the `List` method call must be changed to `ToList`.